# How can I use my android tablet (along with stylus pen) as external display on linux (Ubuntu 20)

Tags: ubuntu, display, android, touch-screen, tablet

I am running Ubuntu 20 on my ASUS VivoBook laptop.  I have many PDF files (of research papers) that I often read and annotate.  At present, I transfer the files to my S6 Lite tablet (an android tablet) to read and annotate the files there using the stylus pen S-pen.  However, this creates multiple copies of files, which are harder for me to find and maintain in the long run.  I was wondering if I could directly annotate the files in the laptop by using the android tablet and its stylus pen.

The laptop itself doesn't have touchscreen.  Is there a way to use the tablet as an external monitor for the laptop and use the S-pen to annotate the PDF files on the laptop?

Comment: There are several answers using vnc on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/750497/421483).

Answer (score 0):

There is a package named [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus) (for Wayland). I haven't been able to get it to work at all on Fedora 34 and a Samsung tablet A (with stylus), others praise it. Haven't looked too recently, though.